# ORDER BY in ORMLite

Tags: android, database

i used blob section to store this value:

```
@DatabaseField(dataType= DataType.SERIALIZABLE)
RatingValues rating;
```

and RatingValues class contain two values

```
 String count;
String rating;
```

now i want to get list of this data with orderby count. Is there any way to use order by in blob section data in ormlite.

Comment: I'm not sure about Ormlite provide support such case but you can use Comparator after get all data from database to sort required data.

Comment: okk but i was finding that is it possible or not